# How fix BeanCreationException issue?

Tags: java, spring

I have web application with the repository

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

My application config is:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan("ru.dev.avtonomki.model")
@ComponentScan("ru.dev.avtonomki")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
   }
}
```

When run sprint-boot i got the issue:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:240)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getSingletonFactoryBeanForTypeCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:923)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:804)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isTypeMatch(AbstractBeanFactory.java:558)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:432)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:395)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:220)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1267)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1101)
```

Comment: where is package of `User` and `UserRepository`?

Comment: User - ru.dev.avtonomki.model, UserRepository - ru.dev.avtonomki.repository. Do you think package make sence?

Comment: yes. `@ComponentScan` scans beans that you defined in its input array. if your bean is not in declared package address(es), you see  `BeanCreationException`. (of course you should add `@Repository` too.)

Answer (score 0):

You have to annotate your repository with `@Repository` like so,

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

As of Spring 2.5, this annotation also serves as a specialization of `@Component`, allowing for implementation classes to be autodetected through classpath scanning.